# How to display CSS files in Django blog?

Tags: css, django, static, blogs

i'm very confused about how to add css files to a blog a made on django following this tutorial: http://www.programmersbook.com/page/21/Django-Beginner-Tutorial-Part-I/

Basically, i want to add a css style sheet to my blog. I've looked around a bit and seen somethings about static and media files and urls. I read a bit about them on Django's website but coulnd't fully understand them.

So, could anyone kindly tell me how i should display:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

They styles work when i do it internally, but how do i show external stylesheets?

Comment: What do you mean, "external stylesheets"?

Comment: not embeded into a html file, but a .css file. In this case, the style.css file.

Comment: Did you read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/

Comment: yes, but i couldn't understnad the staticfiles_dir

Comment: my css files are in a templates folder within the django project folder. Should i rename that folder statics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's right in the Django docs, check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#basic-usage). Follow the instructions there and you will be able to use something like that:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}style.css" />
```

EDIT:
You should sepearate you "static" files from your templates. So move all your .css, .js and images to one directory in your app (it's default name is `/static`). Honestly, everything is written in the link provided.

Comment: does the directory holding the static files have to be called "static"?

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll try it. Should the statics folder be inside the project folder or inside the templates folder?

Comment: I've edited my answer. By default it's called `/static` and, unless you have a strong reason to do otherwise, use that name. You can define additional dirs by setting `STATICFILES_DIRS` in you settings. For example `STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/path/to/my/app/custom_static_dir_name',)`